# Nested tables in Powerapps - remove "Value" column when parsing JSON

Tags: json, powerapps-canvas

Good morning,

I'm hoping someone can assist me with a JSON file. I have a Powerapps canvas app which collates many tables of data in to a final collection on the last screen. This should then be converted to a JSON file to be used by Power Automate to send it to the service endpoint for our sql database.

The issue, is that anywhere in the collection where there is a nested table, such as 'areas', 'auditors' etc the JSON ends up with the column name 'Value' inserted. I need to remove this so that these tables are displayed as simple arrays...

i.e. "areas":[{1},{2}} rather than "areas":[{"Value":1},{"Value":1}]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Amanda

My collect statement is below...it takes values from several other collections throughout the app.

```
This is my collect statement before it's sent to the flow.                       
Collect(
SubmitAuditRequest,
{
    results: [
        {
            questionKey: Value(lblQKey.Text),
            answer: txtQSCM.Text,
            addToActionPlan: false,
            additionalComments: txtQComments.Text,
            typeCode: 1,
            score: txtQGrade.Text,
            actions: [
                {
                    parentKey: 1,
                    parentTypeCode: "RECORD_PARENT_TYPE_##3",
                    action: txtQActions.Text,
                    dateRequired: txtQActionDue.Text,
                    assignedToKey: LblQUserKey.Text,
                    statusCode: "ACTION_STATUS_TYPE_##1",
                    priorityCode: "PRIORITY_TYPE_##3"
                }
            ],
            attachments: [
                {
                    parentKey: 1,
                    parentTypeCode: "RECORD_PARENT_TYPE_##2",
                    documentBase64: "",
                    name: "New Image",
                    extension: "img",
                    attachmentTypeCode: "RECORD_DOCUMENT_TYPE_##1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    organisationKey: 1,
    name: "TestAudit",
    typeCode: "AUDIT_TYPE_##1",
    statusCode: "AUDIT_STATUS_TYPE_##1",
    auditors: [
        1,
        2
    ],
    auditDate: Text(
        Today(),
        "yyyy-mm-dd"
    ),
    staffLeadList: [
        1,
        2
    ],
    areas: [
        1,
        2
    ],
    attachments: [
        {
            parentKey: 2,
            parentTypeCode: "RECORD_PARENT_TYPE_##2",
            documentBase64: "",
            name: "Image 01",
            extension: "img",
            attachmentTypeCode: "RECORD_DOCUMENT_TYPE_##1"
        },
        {
            parentKey:2,
            parentTypeCode: "RECORD_PARENT_TYPE_##2",
             documentBase64: "",
            name: "AudioClip",
            extension: ".3gp",
            attachmentTypeCode: "RECORD_DOCUMENT_TYPE_##2"
        }
    ],
    staffList: [
        3,
        4
    ],
    focusArea: [
        "Focus"
    ],
    focusSubArea: [
        "Focus Area",
        "Focus Area 2"
    ],
    successCriteria: [
        "Success Criteria 1",
        "Success Criteria 2"
    ],
    comment: "No comment",
    Key: 0,
    userKey: 1,
    IsActive: true
}
```

);
SubmitAudit.Run(
JSON(SubmitAuditRequest),
userSettings.token
);

[image: SumbitAuditRequestJSON]
[image: SubmitAuditRequest Collection]

Comment: How are you creating the collections upstream? Please add your `Collect` / `ClearCollect` statements. The answer is based on that.

Comment: @SeaDude I've added my collect statement to my original post. Does this help?

Comment: When you say "...so that these tables are displayed as simple arrays...", are you trying to display the collection in your app? Like in a gallery control?